# Android cant open xml files in my app(Xamarin)

Tags: android, xml, file, xamarin, android-intent

tell me please, why android dont see my app when i try to open xml file

```
  [Activity(Label = "App3", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionSend }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable }, DataMimeType = @"text/xml")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionSend }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable }, DataMimeType = @"application/xml")]
```

If i change xml on pdf its works fine, but not with xml
And must say that my app can safe(share) files but cant open xml files from another apps :(

Comment: Any errors messages?

Comment: No one. I save file, then i look at mime type of it. It was text/xml. Then i share it at to google drive. So i try to open it and my app cant

Comment: If i try do similar with pdf it works fine